# Mybatis : Oracle Nested Collection

Tags: mybatis, oracle-type

How to use **mybatis mappers (without type handlers)** for fetching **DB nested collections** from a stored procedure.
eg: the stored procedure returns a DB table object of the following type :

```
TYPE class_list IS TABLE OF class ;
```

where

```
TYPE class AS OBJECT (students student_list, class_teacher teacher);
TYPE student_list IS TABLE OF student;
TYPE student AS OBJECT (name VARCHAR2, age NUMBER, marks NUMBER);
TYPE teacher AS OBJECT (name VARCHAR2, qualification VARCHAR2, phone_number NUMBER);
```

Comment: IMO, you cannot. Mappers are an answer for common use cases. Fetching complex (vendor dependent) types is more out of the box, and then requires type Handlers.

Comment: Rightly said @blackwizard . There are a bunch of typehandlers provided by MyBatis for known types like varchar, number etc. But for custom objects, there is a need for a custom typeHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@blackwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39150971/#comment68707506_39150971), you are correct. For custom DB types, a custom type handler is a must. Here is the syntax (`jdbcTypeName`) to tell mybatis that it is dealing with a custom object:

```
{call YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_PROCEDURE(
    #{your_input_parameter, jdbcType=VARCHAR mode=IN javaType=java.lang.String mode=IN },
    #{your_output_parameter, jdbcType=ARRAY mode=OUT jdbcTypeName=class_list typeHandler=custom_typeHandler})}
```

**Note**: This is not supported in the deprecated `parameterMap`.

Comment: any chance you could share an example of that typeHandler?